# Start erlang with user defined variable (using rebar)?

Tags: erlang

I'd like to be able to use the following macro in my modules:

```
-ifdef(debug).
```

My startup script looks something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
PWD="$(pwd)"
#NAME="$(basename $PWD)"
erl -pa "$PWD/ebin" deps/*/ebin -boot start_sasl \
    -name foo@127.0.0.1 \
    -debug 1 \
    -s $NAME \
    +K true \
    +P 65536
```

What else would need to be added so that debug is defined in my module? I need this to be dynamic so I don't have to modify source code for deployment into production. Using different startup scripts per dev/qa/prod environments is fine, but modifying source code shouldn't be necessary.

With `erlc` this can be done with `-Ddebug`. I use rebar however, and am not sure how to do it with that. I've tried adding the following to my rebar.config:

`{erl_opts, [{D, "debug"}]}.`

This gives the following error:

```
{error,
 {1,
  erl_parse,
  "bad term"}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The define for the compiler in rebar.config should look like this:

```
{erl_opts, [{d, debug}]}.
```

Note: the syntax is exactly the same as the compiler module's syntax: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html

Current version of rebar (rebar version: 2 date: 20111205_155958 vcs: git 54259c5) does support compiler defines, as well.

```
rebar -D <defines> compile
```

See rebar --help for more rebar options.

Answer (score 1):

ifdef is a preprocessor macro, it gets evaluated and removed at compile time -- you would have to re-compile your module with something like `erlc -Ddebug module.erl` to change it.  add the "-P" flag if you want to see the output from the preprocessor in module.P.

to get access to the "-debug 1" argument at runtime, you can use `init:get_argument(debug)`.

```
# erl -debug 1
...
1> init:get_argument(debug).
{ok,[["1"]]}
2> init:get_argument(foo).  
error
```

Comment: so how would something like this be handled for production deployment? manually editing modules to remove the debug preprocessor?

Comment: for production, you would compile without the -Ddebug flag.  no need to edit the source code.

Comment: I should have noted, I'm using rebar to compile. So I don't have explicit access to ``erlc``